# compare php string to column.. what is not matching?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a php comma separated string 
`$string = (x,y,z)`

I have a column in mysql that has items (y,z)

I want to make an array of the items that are in the string but not in the table column...

```
 $cid = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $cid) . "'";

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT save_key FROM saved WHERE save_key IN ($cid)");

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $array[] = $result['save_key'];
    }

    $cid_array = explode(',',$cid);

    $dif = array_diff($cid_array, $array);

    print_r($dif);
```

Output:

Array from query ( [0] => O45527 [1] => P97387 [2] => Y49437 )

Array from array_dif ( [0] => 'P97387' [1] => 'O45527' [2] => 'Y49437' ) 
all items are the same right..

`print_r($dif);` should return array()

Comment: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_diff` - it Computes the difference of arrays

Just convert your strings in to array using `explode` and use `array_diff`

Example :

```
<?php

$array1=explode(",",$string);
$array2=explode(",",$yourstring_of_db_column);
$array1 = array("x", "y", "z");
$array2 = array( "y","z");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Note : Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

Array from query ( [0] => O45527 [1] => P97387 [2] => Y49437 )

Array from array_dif ( [0] => 'P97387' [1] => 'O45527' [2] => 'Y49437' )

so O45527 and 'O45527' are different ans same for all that is why it's returning whole array. Try to cast elemet values in same datatype.

Comment: Thanks Teez... I modified the code so that i had two versions of $cid the array without quotes and a quoted comma separated string to be used in the query where IN clause...

Comment: OK. Same problem in your previous question :)

Answer (score 1):

The arrays are not the same because you added surrounding quotes to $cid.

```
$quoted_cid = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $cid) . "'";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT save_key FROM saved WHERE save_key IN ($quoted_cid)");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $array[] = $result['save_key'];
}

$cid_array = explode(',',$cid);

$dif = array_diff($cid_array, $array);

print_r($dif);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$str_array = explode($string);

//database row
$row_array = explode($row->string);

$result = array_diff($str_array, $row_array);
//your resultant array is $result.

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

First [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) your string by the commas, then the [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) to compute the difference.